# Tips to find magnitude of 2 forces when given the magnitude of their resultant

Tags: vectors, physics

Forces **A** and **B** has a resultant force **C** with magnitude of 200N.
The magnitudes of **A** and **B** have the relation of **2||A||=3||B||**.
$\theta$ is the angle between **A** and **C**, and the angle between **B** and **C** is 2$\theta$.
Determine the value of $\cos\theta$ and $\cos2\theta$.
Then find **||A||** and **||B||**.

General tips to get me started on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**
Given the angles, the angle between $A$ and $B$ will be $3\theta$ (As $A,B,C$ must lie in a plane).
We have
$$\tag12|A|=3|B|$$
$$\tag2|C|=\sqrt{|A|^2+|B|^2+2|A||B|\cos3\theta}$$

If the angle between $A$ and $C$ is $\alpha$ and that between $A$ and $B$ is $\theta$, then
$$\tag3\tan\alpha=\frac{|B|\sin\theta}{|A|+|B|\cos\theta}$$
Here, replace $\alpha$ with $\theta$ and $\theta$ with $3\theta$.
$$\tag4|C|=200$$

Use $(1)$, $(3)$ and $(4)$ to substitute in $(2)$

Comment: Hey thanks for the hint. However, I am to find $\cos\theta$ and $\cos2\theta$ prior to finding $\cos3\theta$, and then finally ||A|| ||B||. Is there a different way to approach this question in this order?

Comment: @Yuxie In $(3)$, you can write $\cos3\theta=4\cos^3\theta-3\cos\theta$, and using that find $\cos\theta$. Then, $\cos2\theta=2\cos^2\theta-1$. Finally, you can use these values and $(1)$ iin $(2)$ to get one of $|A|$ and $|B|$. Then, substitute back in $(1)$ to get the other.

Comment: Sorry for all these questions but, how would you use $\cos3\theta = 4\cos^3\theta-3\cos\theta$ in $(3)$ to find $\cos\theta$?